# How to model a database where one page can have different content types?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship

I have the database table **page** with the fields **contenttype_id** and **content_id**. I want to link a **page** to a **contenttype** via **contenttype_id** and refer to an actual **content** via **content_id**. The problem is contents depend on the **contenttype_id** and are modelled differently, therefore the **content_id** refers to different tables depending on the **contenttype_id**.

```
CREATE TABLE "page"
("id" "INT",
"author" "VARCHAR(45)",
"created" "DATE",
"content_type" "INT",
"content_id" "INT")

CREATE TABLE "contenttype"
("id" "INT",
"name" "VARCHAR(45)")

CREATE TABLE "content_redirect"
("id" "INT",
"url" "VARCHAR(45)")

CREATE TABLE "content_script"
("id" "INT",
"url" "VARCHAR(45)",
"params", "VARCHAR(45)")

CREATE TABLE "content_text"
("id" "INT",
"text" "TEXT")

CREATE TABLE "content_process"
("id" "INT",
"step1" "TEXT",
"step2" "TEXT",
"step3" "TEXT")

CREATE TABLE "content_extprocess"
("id" "INT",
"system_id" "INT",
"process_id" "INT")
```

How to do that? Or is it already theoretically wrong?

Comment: Why is the content being stored in different tables?  Need more info, otherwise I'd replace `content_id` with the actual content because it reads like a one-to-one relationship.

Comment: The possible contents vary from "simple text" to "external script" to  "processes consisting of multiple steps" so the content structure is requiring different tables

Comment: I see no reason in having different tables from your explanation. Why can't we have both simple text and a link to the script in the same table?

Comment: for the script content i would need the fields url and params, for the text content i would only need the field text, for the "external process" i would need the fields system_id and process_id

Comment: So, could you expand the question with a few table examples?

Answer (score 1):

How about this, to start.

[image]

**EDIT**:

```
create table Content (
      ContentID   integer primary key
    , ContentType char(2)
    , ContentText text
) engine=InnoDb;

create table ScriptContent (
      ContentID integer primary key
    , URL       varchar(45)
    , Params    varchar(45)
) engine=InnoDb;
alter table ScriptContent add constraint fk1_ScriptContent foreign key (ContentID) references Content (ContentID);

create table ExternalProcess (
      ContentID integer primary key
    , SystemID  integer
    , ProcessID integer
) engine=InnoDb;
alter table ExternalProcess add constraint fk1_ExternalProcess foreign key (ContentID) references Content (ContentID);
```

Comment: How do you translate the Symbol with the X into SQL. In the end I will have to come up with a model using a MVC-Framework like CakePHP.

Comment: @timpeti. You don't have SQL, you have MyNonSQL.  Just implement the tables.  Damir's model is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the content of the page have different data structure and the content is not suitable to be stored as a simple blob.

Have page table with page_id and content_type_id. You could have different contents in different tables (one per each content_type_id), each content table providing a foreign key column page_id pointing to the page table. The disadvantage would be that you can't make one join to return the contents for all types of pages, but you'll have to build SQL queries based on different values of page.content_type_id field.